TypeScript - PropTypes exact function
How to assign an object to a variable with a type defined using exact()?
For example let's say I have a type
export const MyType = PropTypes.exact({
  id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
})

and a function that receives an argument
public function doSomething(x: InferProps<typeof MyType>) { // does something with x }

Now when I want to call the function with
const y = {
  id: 1,
  name: "y",
}

I get a typescript error like this:
 Argument of type { id: number; name: string; } is not assignable to parameter of type
InferProps<Requireable<Required<InferProps<{     id: Validator<number>;     name: Validator<string>; }>>>>
Property isRequired is missing in type { id: number; name: string; } but required in type
InferPropsInner<Pick<Requireable<Required<InferProps<{     id: Validator<number>;     name: Validator<string>; }>>>, "isRequired">>


React 19
PropTypes was deprecated in 2017 and (along with defaultProps) are removed in React 19.
import { type ReactNode } from "react"

export type MyComponentProps = {
  id: number
  name: string
}

export function MyComponent(props: MyComponentProps): ReactNode {
  // ...
}

Another option is to use React.FC functional component type helper -
import { type FC } from "react"

export type MyComponentProps = {
  id: number
  name: string
}

export const MyComponent: FC<MyComponentProps> = props => { 
  // ...
}

